# Find and replace one CSV from another CSV

Tags: search, sed

I have two CSV files:

```
id.1 id.2    
1 2     
a b
```

and

```
Name id   
John 1   
Amber a
```

Basically one is a list with replacements, other is just a list. I need to replace all instances of id.1 with id.2. Ideally you would do it using OS X terminal. I have found several ways to replace text in multiple files, yet not using multiple strings. 
Thanks All.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly, but you can scan your replacement file noting what needs to be replaced with what value. And then iterate over list file and swap the replacement value with newer value. Something like this:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next} $2 in a{print $1,a[$2]}' replacement.txt list.txt
```

#### Test:

```
$ cat list.txt 
Name id
John 1
Amber a

$ cat replacement.txt 
id.1 id.2
1 2
a b

$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next} $2 in a{print $1,a[$2]}' replacement.txt list.txt 
John 2
Amber b
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you need, you could try `sort` and `join`. With bash-style process substitution, you can do

```
$ join -11 -22 -o 2.1,1.2 <(sort -k1 <(tail -n+2 id12)) <(sort -k2 <(tail -n+2 list))
John 2
Amber b
```

where `id12` is the first file and `list` is the second file.

Comment: I have ended up doing my own way: sed -e 's/^/s\//' -e 's/,/\//' -e 's/$/\/g/' replacementlist.csv > b.temp; sed -f b.temp <filetobereplaced.csv> replaced.csv; rm b.temp